# Fourier Transform of triangle function ()=Δ((t-1)/2)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, transformation, linear-transformations

Can you please tell me if my working is right for the fourier transform of this function: ()=Δ((t-1)/2)

My workings are: [my workings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqZKX.jpg)

I have used the fourier transform standard results. Please could you tell me if I which I have to apply:

1. First the F(t-1), then F(t/2)
2. First the F(t/2) then F(t-1)
3. First the F(t/2) then F(-1/2)

Please tell me where I have gone wrong. ()=Δ((t-1)/2)
My final answer is () = sinc^2(w/2)*e^(-jPif).

Comment: i am basically asking which transformations are applied 1st